# Is it possible to use ZeroMQ sockets in a Django Channels Consumer?

Tags: python, django, websocket, zeromq, django-channels

I've got a hobby project of building an autonomous boat. I now built a GUI using a Vuejs frontend and a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) backend. In this GUI I can see the boat on a map, and send commands to it. Those commands are sent over [ZeroMQ sockets](https://zeromq.org/) which works great.

I'm using [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to send the commands from the frontend over a websocket to the backend and from there I send it on over the ZeroMQ socket. My consumer (which works great) looks as follows:

```
import zmq
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from .tools import get_vehicle_ip_address, get_vehicle_steer_socket

context = zmq.Context()

class SteerConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.forward_steer_socket = get_vehicle_steer_socket(context, get_vehicle_ip_address())

    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print("Passing on the commands from the frontend:", text_data, "to the boat")
        self.forward_steer_socket.send_string(text_data)
```

Next to this I also receive location information from the boat over a ZeroMQ socket which I save to the database. I'm running this in a separate script and the frontend simply polls the backend every 2 seconds for updates. Here's the script receiving the boat info:

```
import os
import django
import zmq
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'server.settings'
django.setup()

# Socket to receive the boat location
context = zmq.Context()
location_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
location_socket.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, True)
location_socket.bind('tcp://*:6001')
location_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

while True:
    boat_location = location_socket.recv_json()
    print(boat_location)
    # HERE I STORE THE BOAT LOCATION in the DB
```

I would now like to add this `location_socket` to the `Consumer` so that the `Consumer` can also receive the boat location on the ZeroMQ socket and send it to the frontend over the websocket.

I can of course simply add the `location_socket` to the `Consumer` its `__init__()` method as follows:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.forward_steer_socket = get_vehicle_steer_socket(context, get_vehicle_ip_address())

    self.location_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    self.location_socket.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, True)
    self.location_socket.bind('tcp://*:6001')
    self.location_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
```

But I obviously cannot include the `while True` loop in the `Consumer`. So from here I'm not sure what to do. I actually don't know whether this is even possible, since Django Channels seems to specifically been made for websockets. I guess I could start using multithreading or multiprocessing libraries, but that is uncharted territory for me.

Does anybody know whether and how it is possible to make a ZeroMQ listener in a Django Channel?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to send message to your consumer directly from your separated script via: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers

When the new client connects to your consumer inside `SteerConsumer` you have `self.channel_name` which is unique for that client. To send message to that consumer you just have to execute (in your example from separated script):

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
# "channel_name" should be replaced for the proper name of course
channel_layer.send("channel_name", {
    "type": "chat.message",
    "text": "Hello there!",
})
```

and add inside your `SteerConsumer` method to handle this message:

```
def chat_message(self, event):
    # Handles the "chat.message" event when it's sent to us.
    self.send(text_data=event["text"])
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that can work. It would still require me to run two things though: django and the separate script. Since I'm dockerizing it I want to minimize it to running one command though. Plus, in general it's less complicated to keep it in one script. If it's really impossible to do it in the consumer this will be a great second option though. I'll test it out later today.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using ZeroMQ here. Is it not possible to connect directly from your boat to the backend using websockets?

Comment: I guess it is, but zeromq is simply the way it has been designed now. I could change it, but then I would still need to make a decision between websockets and mqtt (something a colleague recommended). Do you have experience with mqtt? This is off topic of course, but I'm just wondering. Maybe you have interesting insights.. :-)